# shinyapps.io paths should be to files within the project directory in drop_get function

Tags: r, dropbox, shiny

shinyapps.io: when I proceed with the deployment, the markers show "paths should be to files within the project directory" and the lines are those where there is the drop_get function that download the files I need. `drop_get("/app1/registrazione_1.csv", dtoken = token1, local_file = "~/applicazionemanager/registrazione1.csv" ,overwrite = TRUE)`

In fact my app doesn't work and there is always the message "disconnected from the server"

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

solved!I put the relative path everywhere in the code and everything works.
I wrote: local_file="registrazione1.csv"